# Failed to Install wsl Ubuntu on Windows Server Core via cmdlet Add-AppxPackage

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-server, appx

Please be aware that I'm using Windows Server **Core**.

I was following instruction in https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/wsl/install-on-server but failed at step 2 with following output

```
PS C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\Ubuntu> Add-AppxPackage .\Ubuntu_2004.2021.825.0_x64.appx
Add-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CF6, Package could not be registered.
error 0x80040154: Cannot register the request because the following error was encountered while
initializing the windows.capability extension: Class not registered
.
NOTE: For additional information, look for [ActivityId] 66806e04-39e0-0000-721e-4586939dd801 in the
Event Log or use the command line Get-AppPackageLog -ActivityID 66806e04-39e0-0000-721e-4586939dd801
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-AppxPackage .\Ubuntu_2004.2021.825.0_x64.appx
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\Admin\....825.0_x64.appx:String) [Add-AppxPackage],
   IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DeploymentError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AddAppxPack
   ageCommand
```

And this is the log:

```
PS C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\Ubuntu> Get-AppPackageLog -ActivityID 66806e04-39e0-0000-721e-4586939dd801

Time                      ID           Message
----                      --           -------
7/22/2022 7:08:00 AM      603          Started deployment Add operation on a package with main parameter
                                       Ubuntu_2004.2021.825.0_x64.appx and Options 0 and 0. See
                                       http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing
                                       app deployment issues.
7/22/2022 7:08:00 AM      157          The app package signature was validated for core content of the
                                       app package published by CN=23596F84-C3EA-4CD8-A7DF-550DCE37BCD0.
                                       Payload won't be validated until the files are read.
7/22/2022 7:08:00 AM      216          App manifest validation warning: Declared namespace
                                       http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/appx/2015/build is
                                       inapplicable, it will be ignored during manifest processing.
7/22/2022 7:08:00 AM      170          The streaming reader was created successfully for app package Cano
                                       nicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_2004.2021.825.0_x64__79rhkp1fndg
                                       sc.
7/22/2022 7:08:00 AM      10002        Creating Resiliency File C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepos
                                       itory\c627b8ed-378b-4e72-805d-2449c9e31a35_S-1-5-21-1753274497-723
                                       328134-3285196822-1001_2.rslc for Add Operation on Package Canonic
                                       alGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_2004.2021.825.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc.
7/22/2022 7:08:00 AM      607          Deployment Add operation on package CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntuon
                                       Windows_2004.2021.825.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc has been de-queued and
                                       is running for user SID
                                       S-1-5-21-1753274497-723328134-3285196822-1001.
7/22/2022 7:08:00 AM      854          Successfully added the following uri(s) to be processed:  file:///
                                       C:/Users/Admin/Downloads/Ubuntu/Ubuntu_2004.2021.825.0_x64.appx.
7/22/2022 7:08:00 AM      855          Finished resolving action lists. DeploymentRequest action lists:
                                       addPackageList: CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_2004.2021.82
                                       5.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc.
7/22/2022 7:08:23 AM      8761         AppExecutionAlias directory missing, error code is 0x8007010B.
7/22/2022 7:08:23 AM      573          Setting Sync Enabled status, package family name
                                       CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc, enabled
                                       false.
7/22/2022 7:08:23 AM      612          Could not contact Process Lifetime Management to ensure that no
                                       apps are running during servicing.
7/22/2022 7:08:23 AM      10000        About to service package CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_200
                                       4.2021.825.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc. Setting the package state to
                                       disabled returned with 0x0.
7/22/2022 7:08:23 AM      310          error 0x80040154: Cannot register the request because the
                                       following error was encountered while initializing the
                                       windows.capability extension: Class not registered
                                       .
7/22/2022 7:08:23 AM      300          error 0x80040154: Cannot register the
                                       CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc package due
                                       to the following error: Class not registered
                                       .
7/22/2022 7:08:23 AM      605          The last successful state reached was SingletonRegisterAdd.
                                       Failure occurred before reaching the next state
                                       RegistrationChanged. hr: 0x80073CF6
7/22/2022 7:08:24 AM      310          error 0x80040154: Cannot register the request because the
                                       following error was encountered while initializing the
                                       windows.capability extension: Class not registered
                                       .
7/22/2022 7:08:24 AM      300          error 0x80040154: Cannot register the
                                       CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc package due
                                       to the following error: Class not registered
                                       .
7/22/2022 7:08:24 AM      8761         AppExecutionAlias directory missing, error code is 0x8007010B.
7/22/2022 7:08:24 AM      472          Moving package folder \\?\C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\CanonicalGr
                                       oupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_2004.2021.825.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc to
                                       \\?\C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Deleted\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubu
                                       ntuonWindows_2004.2021.825.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc6a1a0b91-2d32-4678-
                                       b007-71eb13a70934. Result: 0x0.
7/22/2022 7:08:24 AM      10001        Finished servicing package CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_2
                                       004.2021.825.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc. Setting the package state to
                                       enabled returned with 0x0.
7/22/2022 7:08:24 AM      10001        Finished servicing package CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_2
                                       004.2021.825.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc. Setting the package state to
                                       enabled returned with 0x0.
7/22/2022 7:08:24 AM      401          Deployment Add operation with target volume C: on Package Canonica
                                       lGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_2004.2021.825.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc
                                       from:  (Ubuntu_2004.2021.825.0_x64.appx)  failed with error
                                       0x80073CF6. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for
                                       help diagnosing app deployment issues.
7/22/2022 7:08:24 AM      404          AppX Deployment operation failed for package CanonicalGroupLimited
                                       .UbuntuonWindows_2004.2021.825.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc with error
                                       0x80073CF6. The specific error text for this failure is: error
                                       0x80040154: Cannot register the request because the following
                                       error was encountered while initializing the windows.capability
                                       extension: Class not registered
                                       .
```

It seems I should register something called `windows.capability`, what should I do?
I've succeeded once in another Windows Server (with GUI) some time before.
I wonder if it is the problem of the system or if it is the problem of the package itself?

Comment: Keep in mind that Stack Overflow questions should be about *"specific coding, algorithm, or language problems" (i.e. "unique to software development")*.  Installation issues with WSL are usually better suited for one of the sister sites here such as [Super User](https://superuser.com).  As it is about Windows Server Core, it also *might* be appropriate for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com).